# Unable to Run Tests from VSCode

Tags: unit-test, vs-code

Recently, I have been unable to run tests from VSCode, using the 'Run Test' or 'Run All Tests' links that display inline.  I can still run the tests in the Salesforce Developer Console, just not from VSCode.  I get the error message:

> 09:53:46.173 Starting Run Apex Tests
> This class name's value is invalid: [namespace].[namespace]. Provide the name of an Apex class that has test methods.

Where [namespace] is the name of my namespace as defined in the sfdx-project.json file.

This is occurring against a scratch org and I have tried creating new scratch orgs multiple times and still getting the same message.

Currently running sfdx-cli/7.84.2-a2868a68d5 darwin-x64 node-v12.18.3

Comment: Salesforce CLI latest version might be causing (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/811).  Check workaround mentioned here (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/808) in the comments.

Comment: Yep broken at the moment.

Comment: Similar question with alternative solutions:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/414085/108203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vinay thanks for pointing me to that.  It is a new feature that is causing it.  In the settings there is a new feature that needs to be disabled and that fixed it for me.

In Settings:
Salesforcedx-vscode-core > Experimental: Use Apex Library

Disable - Use Apex Library for Apex CLI Commands
[image]