Getting error: This class name's value is invalid: MyNamespace.CampaignControllerTest. Provide the name of an Apex class that has test methods
I am doing what I thought was a very simple test on some small Apex code as part of a package but I am unable to run the test as I get that error. The original code is in a file CampaignController.cls
public with sharing class CampaignController {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Campaign> getCampaignList() {
    return [
      SELECT Id, Name, Status, Type, StartDate
      FROM Campaign
      ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC
      LIMIT 10
    ];
  }
}

The test code is in a file CampaignControllerTest.cls
@isTest
private class CampaignControllerTest {
  // Methods for testing
  @isTest
  static void TestCampaignCount() {
    List<Campaign> campList = MyNamespace.CampaignController.getCampaignList();
    System.assert(campList.Count() > 0);
  }
}

I see the Run Test | Debug Test links in Visual Studio Code above the TestCampaignCount method. When I run the test I get the error message
13:22:16.998 Starting SFDX: Run Apex Tests
This class name's value is invalid: MyNamespace.CampaignControllerTest. Provide the name of an Apex class that has test methods.
I am not sure what I can do to fix this. The class name is within the 40 character limit. I have the test attributes added. Anything else needed?
EDIT: I did see the question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/331755/123311 but that was answered in 2011 2021. I do not have that setting in the current SF extensions in VSCode so cannot change it.
EDIT 2: I suppose that my error is similar to this one Invalid class name value in 2gen packages when running tests in vsCode. However, unlike in that question, I am not able to run the tests in VSCode successfully. I get the same error message there. I have not managed to run them from within the SF org. The org does not see my tests.

This question is similar to: Unable to Run Tests from VSCode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In fact that other question got answered in 2021, not 2011. But I don't see the setting in my VSCode neither (with all Salesforce extensions at the latest version). In any case, this has been observed before and the latest comment there seems to indicate a resolution, although I don't quite understand it. Are you sure you saved all Apex to the org? What happens, if you run the test with sf apex run test?

Yes, sorry that was a typo with 2011. I am not certain that I have saved the apex to the org. The code is part of an app which I am packaging in this project. I believe that it has already been pushed to the scratch org at least once but how and where would I check this in the org?

Open the org in the browser, Setup - Custom Code - Apex Classes ?!

I can see my apex classes there although not the code itself. It says that they are managed so only certain attributes can be changed. I don't know if that means the code itself but I don't see any actual code there. I see the names of the classes only for the example above and I see a method for another class but no code in either.

If you see the class code in VSCode, you are not connected to an org, where this code belongs to an installed managed package (with packaged class code being hidden). I thought you are connected to the org, where you create the package?! If you want to run tests in a test class with hidden code, don't use VSCode. Or have I overlooked/misunderstood anything?

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are saying. I am creating a package and installing it on a scratch org. In VSCode, I can see that I am working with that scratch org. When I go into that scratch org I can see the apex classes but I don't see the code (I assume that is because the package is managed). I thought that I would be able to test the code in VSCode. I just don't really understand the error message because it looks to me that I am doing everything all the other examples say I should be doing. Clearly I am not or there is something broken somewhere.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I wanted to post this as I think it is now working. It was really quite painful to get to the answer.
Based on my original setup I had to do two things.
Firstly, I had to add meta files. I had my CampaignControllerTest.cls class but I also needed a corresponding CampaignControllerTest.cls-meta.xml file. This looked exactly the same as all the other but it needed to be there.
Once I had that, when I attempted to deploy to a scratch org, instead of the usual errors, I started to get errors in my test code coming up. These were fixable.
Once I had fixed those errors and deployed to my scratch org, I was able to click on the Run Test | Debug Test links which actually ran them.
I hope that this helps somebody else. It was painful to get there.
